# Custom attributes in Powershell Module manifest

Tags: powershell

I'm creating my own Powershell Module with a manifest file but I'm not sure if I can add my own custom attribute i.e: Build Number , I realize that the Version Number already exists which made me interested in doing automated builds with it.

Will this affect anything when importing the module to Powershell when I do import-module -module MyModuleName ?

Thanks

Comment: [`Test-ModuleManifest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/test-modulemanifest?view=powershell-3.0) holds the answer to your question. [See also](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/08/24/verify-powershell-module-manifests/).

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new property to the top level of the module manifest will cause it to fail to load. You should add your property to the `PrivateData` hashtable in the manifest.